# Why do Dedekind cuts use sets?

Tags: real-analysis, elementary-set-theory, real-numbers, foundations

As far as I understand Dedekind cuts, they are really about ranges, not sets. In other words, they are about all of the values greater than or less than some number. But by using sets, I'm led to thinking about odd sets of numbers like "all the numbers with a 3 as the third decimal digit", or "all of the numbers that are the cosine of an angle that is a power of two". Is this generality necessary in defining Dedekind cuts? And if so, why?

Comment: What do you mean? [Dedekind cuts](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dedekind_cut) are precisely defined.  They don't include "all" subsets of the rational numbers or anything like that.

Comment: One way or another the real numbers are in bijection with the powerset (i.e. set of subsets) of the naturals. Given that, it's not so unnatural to construct the real numbers as sets with some additional structure.

Comment: I'm finding this question difficult to understand. Dedekind cuts are one of the standard ways to construct the real numbers in $\mathsf{ZFC}$. In $\mathsf{ZFC}$, *everything* is a set, and so it is a necessity that the real numbers are defined as certain sets. Every Dedekind cut is a subset of $\mathbb Q$, but not every subset of $\mathbb Q$ is a Dedekind cut.

Comment: There are both philosophical and logical subtleties here that are difficult to articulate in a comment. To understand them, I would suggest turning to an analysis book: in part 5 of Michael Spivak's *Calculus* (chapters 28 to 30), he explains the concept of a field, the construction of the real numbers, and their uniqueness.

Comment: @Joe, Dedekind are used in other contexts besides modelling the real  numbers in ZFC.

Comment: @DavidGudeman: While that is certainly true, $\mathsf{ZFC}$ is the standard foundation of mathematics. Also, *analysts* themselves don't use Dedekind cuts per se – rather, they use the fact that there exists a complete ordered field. The main theorems of real analysis hold for every complete ordered field (and there is only one such ordered field, up to isomorphism).

Answer (score 5):

"Ranges" are just sets; the "range" of all numbers less than $1$ is (in $\Bbb R$) the set $(-\infty,1)$. On these grounds, I fail to see the issue; I somewhat agree that Dedekind cuts are really about ranges, but there is no issue in encoding those ''ranges" as sets (*what else would you do?*).

On a different note, you remark that "[Dedekind cuts] are about all of the values greater than or less than some number". This is subtle; what is a "number"? If you already have real numbers at your service, then the technical definition of a Dedekind cut might feel a bit silly, since any cut $\mathfrak{p}$ "is" the interval $(-\infty,x)\cap\Bbb Q$ for some real $x$. But the whole point is that we *don't* yet have real numbers at our service. The set $\{q\in\Bbb Q:q<\sqrt{2}\}$ is a true Dedekind cut but it makes absolutely no sense unless you already have a real number field $\Bbb R$ that contains $\Bbb Q$ as a subset... which defeats the point of trying to construct the real numbers (it is horribly circular). In this construction, $\sqrt{2}$ itself *is* a Dedekind cut, e.g. the cut $\{q\in\Bbb Q:q^2<2\vee q<0\}$; we can't describe all Dedekind cuts as intervals using just the rational numbers. The technical definition is designed to capture the idea of "interval" without specifying any explicit upper bounds. The irrational numbers are then the 'strange' cuts which can't be written as rational intervals. A good thing is that we don't need to explicitly define all of our Dedekind cuts; we just define what a cut is and then the basic set-theoretic axioms kick in and give us a set of all cuts, which we call $\Bbb R$. We can then discover that there must exist irrational cuts.

I guess that does mean "this generality [is] necessary"; using only the concept of an interval, you would not be able to define $\Bbb R$ in this way since you would not be able to write down an interval (in the theory of $\Bbb Q$) that describes $\sqrt{2}$, whereas using the technical definition of a cut we can sit back and relax; let our universe provide all the extra, weird, irrational cuts for us and give us the real numbers.

Comment: The reason it matters is because I'm investigating the possibility of defining the real numbers in purely geometric terms without sets. Also, I was assuming I could define ranges with a more general notation such as Range x . x^2 < 2.

Comment: @DavidGudeman Unless you are using some fancy alternative foundations, it will all boil down to sets eventually. The square root of two is just a simple case; imagine trying to express $\pi$ as a Dedekind cut in a clean way… you could even run into issues with not all real being computable or definable or whatever; I have my doubts a truly pure geometric option exists. That said, there is something like the Farey circle (?) representation of representations using continued fractions, which might appeal to you more. I personally like the Cauchy sequence definition, it may feel less set-like

Comment: I know that whatever I come up with will be re-interpretable in terms of sets; the point is that I don't have to assume that sets exist. For example, you can always interpret a range as a set, but you can also view it as something more restricted than a set.